# Changing CSS of one element using jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a couple of elements that I want to change the grayscale of when hovering. Instead of changing all of them at the same time (since they have the same class) I only want to change the one that is currently being hovered.

So I made the following code:

```
tpj(".cftoverlay").hover(function(){
    tpj(this).find(".hoverBorderWrapper > img").css("filter","grayscale(0%)");
    console.log("test");
},function() {
    tpj(this).find(".hoverBorderWrapper > img").css("filter","grayscale(100%)");
    console.log("test1");
});
```

The console log works but for some reason the rest of the code doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

My html structure:

```
<span class="cftoverlay">
    <img src="images/overlay.png">
</span>
<span class="hoverBorderWrapper">
    <img width="750" height="350" src="cms/images/afbeeldingen/artikelen/IMG-20170208-WA0021.jpg" class="img-responsive big-featuredarticles" alt="css3panels-alt-04" title="css3panels-alt-04">
    <span class="theHoverBorder"></span>
</span>
```

The image stays grayscale no matter what since I added some css so it's grayscale when not hovered, but inline css added by jquery should always overwrite that right?

When hovering it, I can see something changing in my element inspector on this line:

```
<span class="cftoverlay">
```

But no css is added anywhere.

Comment: What does `tpj(".cftoverlay")` do?

Comment: try adding class to the img tag and select that one.

Comment: @gurvinder372 tpj is jquery instead of the regular $ sign. On hover of that class it should fire the code beneath it.

Comment: `.find()` only searches through the descendants of `.cftoverlay`, so it will not find the `hoverBorderWrapper` span, as that is a sibling and not a child/descendant

Comment: Note that `.hoverBorderWrapper` isn't a child of `.cftoverlay` then `find()` won't find anything. Also note that simply using a CSS rule :hover is faster and easier, no need JS here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that `tpj` is a reference to jQuery. If so, your issue is because `.hoverBorderWrapper` is not a child of `.cftoverlay` but a sibling instead. You need to use `next()` to retrieve it instead of `find()`:

```
tpj(".cftoverlay").hover(function(){
    tpj(this).next(".hoverBorderWrapper > img").css("filter", "grayscale(0%)");
    console.log("test");
}, function() {
    tpj(this).next(".hoverBorderWrapper > img").css("filter", "grayscale(100%)");
    console.log("test1");
});
```

That said, I'd not use JS for this at all. CSS is more better suited to styling changes under the `hover` event:

```
.hoverBorderWrapper > img {
  filter: grayscale(100%)
}
.cftoverlay:hover + .hoverBorderWrapper > img {
  filter: grayscale(0%)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah CSS is better for this.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using jQuery, use pure CSS.

eg.

```
<img src="images/foo.jpg" class="hoverBorderWrapper"/>

<style>
    .hoverBorderWrapper{
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
        filter: grayscale(100%);
     }

    .hoverBorderWrapper:hover{
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
        filter: grayscale(0%);
     }
</style>
```

Comment: Note that the hover event is triggered on the `.cftoverlay`, not the `. hoverBorderWrapper`, and the result should affect the `img` itself